# how to use AngularJS directive using jQuery append?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have lots of code written in jQuery.
Now I want an approach,Thousand lines of jQuery code is written, so I think it's better to achieve new functionalities using AngularJS. What basically I need is:

I have following code in app.js:

```
var cmsApp = angular.module('cmsApp', []);
cmsApp.controller('OOJRecordTab',['$scope' ,function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.test = function() {
    console.log('Test');
  };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown open">
        <a>Records <span>0</span></a>
        <ul id="oojRecordsLinks" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a ng-click="test()" tabindex="-1">test</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The above click function works perfectly.
Now I have a function in jQuery like:

```
function addNewRecords(html){
    $record = "<a ng-click='test()'></a>";
    $("ul#oojRecordsLinks").append($record);
}
```

Click function for this newly appended row doesn't work. Please suggests.
Someone help me please. It's not working till now.

Comment: Could you please post some of your code here??

Comment: show your html where you want to use this function

Comment: Thanks for your help. QUestion modified, see above..

Comment: Better you create a directive for achieving this

Comment: Can you please show me an example..
How should I achieve that, I have tried and it's also not working ?
code in app.js
`
cmsApp.directive('myLink', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function() {
            console.log('Its clicked');
        });
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };
});
`
and in jQuery:
`
function addNewRecords(html){
        $record = "<a my-link></a>";
        $("ul#oojRecordsLinks").append($record);
    }
`

Comment: Finally I found the answer on my own. Thank you all..
And here's the [Plnkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lkfirfr0Qo3HoviYru29?p=preview)..
Thank you all.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer on my own. We can add using jQUery the newly added html elements, but we need to compile it under the scope with AngularjS..
After working hours and hours, finally I did it..
And here's the [Plnkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lkfirfr0Qo3HoviYru29?p=preview).

Thank you all.. :)